# Converting HashMap into JSONArray, Values are not coming properly

Tags: java, json, elasticsearch, collections

Am getting response from Elasticsearch with duplicates, to avoid that i used `Hashmap` implementation and i `put` all the values into the `HashMap` object.

After that am iterating over the `HashMap` object to convert into JSONArray.

Am geting one unique record from `distinctObjects` (HashMap Object). But after if convert into JSONArray., the length of JSONArray shows `2` it suppose to be `1` and am printing the JSONArray, it shows like below.

```
JSONArray --->[{"code":"VA1125-GGA-1","id":"code"},{"code":"12816","id":"id"}]
```

Expected Result should be :

```
JSONArray --->[{"code":"VA1125-GGA-1","id":"12816"}]
```

Please find my code below.

```
JSONObject responseObj;
JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray();
Map<String, Object> distinctObjects = null;
SearchHit[] searchHits2 = searchResponse2.getHits().getHits();
for (SearchHit hit2 : searchHits2) {
    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap2 = hit2.getSourceAsMap();
    distinctObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    distinctObjects.put("id", sourceAsMap2.get("id").toString());
    distinctObjects.put("code", sourceAsMap2.get("code").toString());
}               

Iterator it = distinctObjects.entrySet().iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry)it.next();
    System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = " + pair.getValue());
    responseObj = new JSONObject();
    responseObj.put("id", pair.getKey());
    responseObj.put("code", pair.getValue());
    responseArray.put(responseObj);
    it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
}

System.out.println("Link ID List Size --->"+responseArray.length());
System.out.println("JSONArray --->"+responseArray.toString());
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're adding both `code` and `id` as top level entries to your distinctObjects map which is why you're getting two objects back. Assuming you want to de-dup based on ID your first loop should look something like:

```
for (SearchHit hit2 : searchHits2) {
    Map<String, Object> sourceAsMap2 = hit2.getSourceAsMap();
    distinctObjects = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    distinctObjects.put(sourceAsMap2.get("id"), sourceAsMap2.get("code").toString());
}
```

That will give you one entry in `distinctObjects` for every unique id with a value of the `code`.

If you wanted you could also add `sourceAsMap2` as the value in `distinctObjects` to maintain the full response if you need more than just the `code` in downstream processing.

Comment: Thanks a lot., I made, downstream Processing like this `Collection<Object> values = distinctObjects.values();
         JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(values);
         for(int i=0;i<jsonArray.length();i++) {
         JSONObject jsonObj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
         responseObj = new JSONObject();
            responseObj.put("id", jsonObj.optString("id"));
            responseObj.put("code", jsonObj.optString("code"));
            responseArray.put(responseObj);
         }`